# How to extract a substring using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, text-extraction

I have a string that has two single quotes in it, the `'` character. In between the single quotes is the data I want.

How can I write a regex to extract "the data i want" from the following text?

```
mydata = "some string with 'the data i want' inside";
```

Answer (score 722, accepted):

Assuming you want the part between single quotes, use this regular expression with a [`Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
"'(.*?)'"
```

Example:

```
String mydata = "some string with 'the data i want' inside";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result:

```
the data i want
```

Comment: damn .. i always forget about the non greedy modifier :(

Comment: replace the "if" with a "while" when you expect more than one occurences

Comment: mind that matcher.find() is needed for this code sample to work. failing to call this method will result in a "No match found" exception when matcher.group(1) is called.

Comment: If you want the first result it should be ".group(0)" and not ".group(1)".

Comment: @mFontoura group(0) would return the complete match with the outer ' '. group(1) returns what is in-between the ' ' without the ' ' themselves.

Comment: why does Mark use the question mark in this case? doesn't the .* match 0 or more anyway? So if there was an empty string between the two quotations it would match nonetheless?

Comment: This code works well, but in the result the delimiters (') is included. How to get the substring without the delimiters?

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading, as the code provided returns `'the data i want'` instead of `the data i want`. If you want to remove the single quotes you should print `matcher.group(1)` instead.

Comment: @BooRadley The answer was correct from the beginning, I made rollback.

Comment: @Larry this is a late reply, but ? in this case is non-greedy modifier, so that for `this 'is' my 'data' with quotes` it would stop early and return `is` instead of matching as many characters as possible and return `is' my 'data`, which is the default behavior.

Answer (score 82):

You don't need regex for this.

Add apache commons lang to your project (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), then use:

```
String dataYouWant = StringUtils.substringBetween(mydata, "'");
```

Comment: You have to take into account how your software will be distributed. If it is something like a webstart it's not wise to add Apache commons only to use this one functionality. But maybe it isn't. 
  Besides Apache commons has a lot more to offer. Even tough it's good to know regex, you have to be carefull on when to use it. 
  Regex can be really hard to read, write and debug. Given some context using this could be the better solution.

Comment: Sometimes StringUtils is already there, in those cases this solution is much cleaner and readable.

Comment: Its like buying a car to travel 5 miles (when you are traveling only once in a year).

Comment: While substring looks for a specific string or value, regex looks for a format. It's more and more dynamic. You need regex, if you are looking for a pattern instead of a special value.

Answer (score 21):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*'([^']*)'.*");
        String mydata = "some string with 'the data i want' inside";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(matcher.group(0));  <--- Zero based index

Comment: No. group(0) has special meaning, capturing groups start at index group(1)
 (i.e. group(1) is correct in the answer). 

"Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern" - Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-

Comment: Bear in mind that `matches()` tries to match entire string, so if you don't have ".*" at the beginning and end of your pattern, it won't find anything.

Comment: +1 (or +100 if I could) for "import" statements !  no idea why people leave these out when writing answers.

Answer (score 20):

There's a simple one-liner for this:

```
String target = myData.replaceAll("[^']*(?:'(.*?)')?.*", "$1");
```

By making the matching group optional, this also caters for quotes not being found by returning a blank in that case.

See [live demo](http://ideone.com/f1Ann2).

Answer (score 17):

#### Since Java 9

As of this version, you can use a new method [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) with no args that is able to comfortably return `Stream<MatchResult>` where [`MatchResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html) represents the result of a match operation and offers to read matched groups and more (this class is known since Java 1.5).

```
String string = "Some string with 'the data I want' inside and 'another data I want'.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
pattern.matcher(string)
       .results()                       // Stream<MatchResult>
       .map(mr -> mr.group(1))          // Stream<String> - the 1st group of each result
       .forEach(System.out::println);   // print them out (or process in other way...)
```

The code snippet above results in:

> ```
> the data I want
> another data I want
> ```

The biggest advantage is in the ease of usage when one or more results is available compared to the procedural `if (matcher.find())` and `while (matcher.find())` checks and processing.

Answer (score 11):

Because you also ticked Scala, a solution without regex which easily deals with multiple quoted strings:

```
val text = "some string with 'the data i want' inside 'and even more data'"
text.split("'").zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % 2 != 0).map(_._1)

res: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(the data i want, and even more data)
```

Comment: So readable solution, thats why people love scala I belive :)

Comment: Why not just `.split('\'').get(2)` or something to that extent in Java? I think you may need to get a brain scan if you think that's a readable solution - it looks like someone was trying to do some code golf to me.

Answer (score 10):

```
String dataIWant = mydata.replaceFirst(".*'(.*?)'.*", "$1");
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer ? Like why use `replaceFirst` ? Why `$1` ?

Comment: @Elikill58 That's actually pretty clever. `.*'` matches everything before the first `'`, including, and `'.*` matches everything else afterwards. `(.*?)` is a group that captures everything between the ticks non-greedily, I think.  `$1` means that we want to replace what was matched by the regexp (everything in this case) by contents of the first capture group (`(.*?)` that matches everything between ticks). `$0` would have meant the whole regexp.

Answer (score 3):

as in javascript:

```
mydata.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1]
```

the actual regexp is: `/'([^']+)'/`

if you use the non greedy modifier (as per another post) it's like this:

```
mydata.match(/'(.*?)'/)[1]
```

it is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

`String dataIWant = mydata.split("'")[1];`

See [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/kxgTaU)

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Lang provides a host of helper utilities for the java.lang API, most notably String manipulation methods. 
In your case, the start and end substrings are the same, so just call the following function.

> ```
> StringUtils.substringBetween(String str, String tag)
> ```
>
> Gets the String that is nested in **between two instances of the same
>   String**.

If the start and the end substrings are different then use the following overloaded method.

> ```
> StringUtils.substringBetween(String str, String open, String close)
> ```
>
> Gets the String that is nested in between two Strings.

If you want all instances of the matching substrings, then use,

> ```
> StringUtils.substringsBetween(String str, String open, String close)
> ```
>
> Searches a String for substrings delimited by a start and end tag,
>   **returning all matching substrings in an array**.

For the example in question to get all instances of the matching substring

```
String[] results = StringUtils.substringsBetween(mydata, "'", "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala,

```
val ticks = "'([^']*)'".r

ticks findFirstIn mydata match {
    case Some(ticks(inside)) => println(inside)
    case _ => println("nothing")
}

for (ticks(inside) <- ticks findAllIn mydata) println(inside) // multiple matches

val Some(ticks(inside)) = ticks findFirstIn mydata // may throw exception

val ticks = ".*'([^']*)'.*".r    
val ticks(inside) = mydata // safe, shorter, only gets the first set of ticks
```

Answer (score 1):

add **apache.commons** dependency on your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And below code works.

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(String mydata, String "'", String "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this 
i use while loop to store all matches substring in the array  if you use

`if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}`

you will get on matches substring  so you can use this to get all matches substring

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(text);
   // Matcher  mat = pattern.matcher(text);
    ArrayList<String>matchesEmail = new ArrayList<>();
        while (m.find()){
            String s = m.group();
            if(!matchesEmail.contains(s))
                matchesEmail.add(s);
        }

    Log.d(TAG, "emails: "+matchesEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some how the group(1) didnt work for me. I used group(0) to find the url version.

```
Pattern urlVersionPattern = Pattern.compile("\\/v[0-9][a-z]{0,1}\\/");
Matcher m = urlVersionPattern.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) { 
    return StringUtils.substringBetween(m.group(0), "/", "/");
}
return "v0";
```