# find the value between quotation marks in a string and store the value in a variable

Tags: javascript

I fount this link regarding my post [How to extract a substring using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex#4662265) but it is in java.

let's say i have a sentence:

```
var sentence = "This is a long sentence but I only want this 'information'";
```

Then i want to extract the value in the quotation marks (the value: information) and store it in a variable. What do I do?

Comment: What have you tried doing? Do you know that JavaScript has Regex [as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.indexOf()`, `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`

```js
var sentence = "This is a long sentence but I only want this 'information'";

var res = sentence.slice(sentence.indexOf("'") + 1, sentence.lastIndexOf("'"));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to the Java-based one in the link you gave:

```js
var sentence = "This is a long sentence but I only want this 'information'";
var re = new RegExp("'(.*?)'");
console.log(sentence.match(re));
```