# Extracting a pattern from a string in Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a `String` variable as follows in Java.

```
String s = "hello\nthis is java programme\n.class file will be generated after executing it\n";
```

Now I need to exctract the `.class` part from the above string variable. How to do that?

Comment: If you just need the `.class`, then just use `".class"`. I assume you wanted something else? Can you define it more precisely? Show what your output string should be?

Comment: I'd suggest regex but I don't get your requirements. What would the `.class` part be?  If it's just the literal then what do you mean by "extract"?

Comment: It is just a pattern I am trying to extract from the string.

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: do you want everything up to the .class? after the .class? what?

Comment: Please provide more and better examples of that pattern. Would the string be something like `"yadda yadda ...\nWhatever.class file will be generated..."` and you want to extract `Whatever`?

Comment: The output should be " `.class` " alone.

Comment: Then you don't need the original string and you don't need to "extract" anything. If you want `.class`, use `System.out.println(".class")`. Otherwise, explain what you want in your output that has anything to do with your input.

Comment: How about `String output = ".class";`? I know that sounds silly and is probably not what you are looking for _but we really don't know what it is that you want_.

Comment: If output should be `.class`, then write `String output = ".class";` and you're done.

Comment: @SasiKanth As you can see from previous comments, your description of what you want is extremely badly worded. Perhaps you should read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I really only see one way for you to not simply just output ".class" which is to first see if the string contains ".class" before printing it.
Here is a function to do so. Pass a string to look for and a string to search for it.

```
//Returns the string if found, else returns an empty string
public String FindString(String whatToFind, String whereToFind)
{
    return whereToFind.contains(whatToFind) ? whatToFind : "";
}
```

Output

```
String s = "hello\nthis is java programme\n.class file will be generated after executing it\n";
System.out.println(FindString(".class", s)); // prints .class
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to check if the string has ".class" pattern inside you can easily just check it like:

```
s.contains(".class");
```

Or if you want check that the pattern like `.class` inside your string that contains `\n` using regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\.class.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean b = m.matches();
```

`DOTALL` enables `\n` also considered as a character.

*s is the String you defined in your code.*

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)

```
String s = "hello\nthis is java programme\n<some_class_name_here>.class file will be generated after executing it\n";
//the following pattern I think will find what you're looking for,
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\n(.*\.class)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: People really want to help you, but as the comments indicate, your question is not clear. I'll try to restate what I think you're asking:

I have a `String` variable which has the following structure in Java.

    String s = "hello\nthis is java programme\n<some_class_name_here>.class file will be generated after executing it\n";

Now I need to extract the `<some_class_name_here>.class` part from the above string variable so that I have a variable with only the class and the .class portion of the string. How do I extract only the classname and .class bit of the String?