# Extract letter from String characters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have these `Strings`:

```
"Turtle123456_fly.me"
"birdy_12345678_prd.tr"
```

I want the first words of each, ie:

```
Turtle
birdy
```

I tried this:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("//d");
 String[] items = p.split(String);
```

but of course it's wrong. I am not familiar with using `Pattern`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)

Comment: Better you could have used string.tochararray() and check the ASCII code you will get your answer...!

Comment: @Shailesh Like [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-string-to-char-array-in-java/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the stuff you don't want with nothing:

```
String firstWord = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z].*", "");
```

to leave only the part you want.

The regex `[^a-zA-Z]` means "not a letter", the everything from (and including) the first non-letter to the end is "removed".

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/oHUIN2).

Comment: Then the output for `Turtle123456_fly.me` would be `Turtleflyme` not `Turtle`

Comment: @Ocean no it wouldn't. I used `a-zA-Z`, not `\w`, and `.*` runs to the end.

Comment: Ah jeah sorry, my bad. Then this is the way to go. Way easier than the other solution

Comment: @Ocean it's always good to question and doubt! I have added a link to a live demo to quell your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s1 ="Turtle123456_fly.me";
String s2 ="birdy_12345678_prd.tr";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z]+)[^A-Za-z]");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s1);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Explanation:
The first part `^([A-Za-z]+)` is a group that captures all the letters anchored to the beginning of the input (using the ^ anchor).
The second part `[^A-Za-z]` captures the first non-letter, and serves as a terminator for the letters sequence.
Then all we have left to do is to fetch the group with index 1 (group 1 is what we have in the first parenthesis).

Comment: Please don't post code and tell "try this"... This community is about learning stuff, not about sharing source-code... Explain what are the main parts of the code, and what those parts of the code do, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this `\d+\w+.*`