# How to extract a substring using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string, text-extraction

I have the following string :

```
String xmlnode = "<firstname id="{$person.id}"> {$person.firstname} </firstname>";
```

How can I write a regex to extract the data inside the `{$STRING_I_WANT}`

The part I need is without `{$}` how can I achieve that?

Comment: `[\{](.*?)[\}]` - Full match includes brackets, but if you want the data inside then use the group match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex `\{\$(.*?)\}` with pattern like this :

```
String xmlnode = "<firstname id=\"{$person.id}\"> {$person.firstname} </firstname>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\$(.*?)\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlnode);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Note :** you have to escape each character `{` `$` `}` with `\` because each one is special character in regex.

**Outputs**

```
person.id
person.firstname
```