# Regex to capture words between the first colon : and the last square brackets having colon : in it

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a String which I want to parse.
The String is like this :-

```
00:0qwe8.0 donald controller duck [02009&123@##]: Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#][15b:31013]
```

Notice the last Square bracket has a : colon in it. and the character before *Some More* is also a colon. I want to capture all the characters between them.

Currently I am parsing it with the following regex in two steps.Here is the java code.

```
class JavaReg{

 public static void main(String[] args){

   String str = "00:0qwe8.0 donald controller duck [02009&123@##]: Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#][15b:31013]";
   String[] strArr = str.split("\\[.*?\\]\\:\\s");
   String[] str12 = strArr[1].split("\\[\\w*?\\:.*");
   for(String strinj : strArr)
      System.out.println(strinj);

   System.out.println(str12[0]);
 }

}
```

The following is the result of the above exercise.

```
00:0qwe8.0 donald controller duck
Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#][15b:31013]
Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#]
```

The last string is what I want. It starts capturing from the colon : and goes on to capture till the Square bracket which has a colon.

The question is can I use capturing groups in regex to capture it in one shot.
How to do that in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)

Comment: No, this is not duplicate. It has its own specific uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex to extract the match:

```
\[[^\]\[]*\]:\s*(.*?)\[\w*:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jPGftE/1).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `\]:` -  a `]:` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\[` - `[` char
- `\w*` - 0+ letter, digits or `_`
- `:` - a colon.

Use it with `Matcher#find()` and grab `matcher.group(1)`, see the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GK5kd7):

```
String str = "00:0qwe8.0 donald controller duck [02009&123@##]: Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#][15b:31013]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\]:\\s*(.*?)\\[\\w*:");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#]
```

Comment: Yeah man, both of the answers are good, I was also in dilemma, the other one came earlier so I picked it. But Thanks Sir.

Comment: @JohnDoe My answer was posted at 11:18:32 and the other one was posted at 11:18:40. My answer was posted earlier.

Comment: Done dude done, but please explain this one from your answer \[[^\]\[]*\]

Comment: @JohnDoe It is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any single char that does not belong to the specified char set. So, it matches any char but `[` and `]`. These inside must be escaped since they are used to form character class unions and intersections.

Comment: So you could have written [^ \\] \\[ ]*  like this as well [^\\[ \\] ]* .

Comment: @JohnDoe `[^\]\[]` can be written as `[^\[\]]`. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this single regex to capture the string you want:

```
(?<=\]: ).*(?=\[)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kd9o0E/2)**

Here, `(?<=\]: )` this positive look behind matches `]:` literally to match your data like you mentioned, and from that point onwards, greedily captures everything till it sees last `[` which also contains a colon, and although since that was the point till where you wanted to capture, I didn't put constraints for colon further.

But in case you want to also enforce it should stop matching just before a `[something1:something2]`, then you can use this regex,

```
(?<=\]: ).*(?=\[[^[\]]*:[^[\]]*\])
```

**[Demo with a finer regex](https://regex101.com/r/kd9o0E/5)**

The Java code

```
String s = "00:0qwe8.0 donald controller duck [02009&123@##]: Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#][15b:31013]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\]: ).*(?=\\[[^\\[\\]]*:[^\\[\\]]*\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints:

```
Some more sring here Model number 420 Family [Super-cool] [15b31013^^@#]
```

Comment: (.*) I can understand that you are using this to capture the group but please explain how your regex.

Comment: Thanks but please clarify this one a little bit more (?<=\]: )

Comment: `(?<=]: )` this is called positive look behind expression and marks the point which is preceded by exactly `]: ` literal. Notice it has `]` `:` and a space. [Check the pink pointer in this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kd9o0E/4) which shows the beginning of capture.

Comment: So this is (?=\[) positive lookahead which matches the last [ (square bracket) correct?

Comment: Yes, not `(?=[)` but this `(?=\[)` Escaping `[` is necessary as `[` has a special meaning in regex. But in case you want the match to stop just before a `[something:something]` then even better positive look ahead regex is `(?=\[[^[\]]*:[^[\]]*\])` which will ensure it only stops at a bracket containing a colon inside and doesn't matter whether it is last or not. [Check the pink pointer in this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kd9o0E/6) which shows the end mark till where the data will be captured.