# Regex to find database name from Jdbc url

Tags: java, regex, string

What will be the regular expression forbelow jdbc urls to find the databaseName. Output will be "ab_cd_e".

```
String jdbcUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:1440;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER2019;integratedSecurity=false;databaseName=ab_cd_e";
String jdbcUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:1440;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER2019;databaseName=ab_cd_e;integratedSecurity=false";
```

I have tried:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(;databaseName=)(.*?)([;])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: SO is not a "do it for me" service. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans yes, i have tried -  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(;databaseName=)(.*?)([;])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Comment: You can try to get correct pattern with help of [this](https://regex101.com/) site. Please try it.

Comment: Your first problem is the `^` means to start matching at the _beginning_ of your string.  The other problem is your regex states that the databaseName _must_ be followed by a semicolon.  Lastly, your full match has more information than you want, so you have to make sure you get the correct capture group; or better yet, use lookarounds like @Hülya did.

Comment: You could use a single capturing group with a negated character class instead of the non greedy dot to get the name. `;databaseName=([^;s]+)(?:;|$)` https://regex101.com/r/k8iZpD/1 or split the string on `;` and filter by databaseName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to extract the string between the parts `databaseName=` and `;` or `$` end of line. To achieve this you can use a positive lookahead `(?=;|$)` and a positive lookbehind `(?<=databaseName=)`

Hence, the regex `(?<=databaseName=)\\w+(?=;|$)` gives you `ab_cd_e`

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=databaseName=)\\w+(?=;|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jdbcUrl);
if (matcher.find()) 
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
;databaseName=([^;]*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/yaU0DY/1/)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;databaseName=           ';databaseName='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^;]*                    any character except: ';' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

[Java code](http://%3Ca%20href=%22https://tio.run/##pZE/b8IwEMXn5FOcmJJWNVCxNFGmiq1ULam6UIoujgmmiZPaF/4I8dmpIQEJqZ3q5Vln/d67Oy9xhXfL9OtwkEVVaoKlLbCaZM60yMSG3YQuuDxHY@BNGHo83tyd61R1kksOhpCsrEqZQoFSgReTliqbTAF1ZnyghS7XprHNUWVsuOGiIlkq17E2zlwqzKGB4BQJEXTCFAkTNOIZCxF5k89weuN3QtcBe64Q04hllmnCA/OdG6FXQgfdLiac8bII@oNBL5TKtqp4YziK49eneDh@H47ve/2H6zRMZjydCUuQyDSSSGPBay1pG83Run@oDtz@K@4v51/7OE/djv2CREIrqFqNzpVjdiVz4Z2W6F9TIyS@ENp@UaPRmWdtxWv2eMHWC2sFXvvKrEvq@T7s2meAeGtIFKysiVWWpFx5nWPbARy3c@YyXdaV1/cvvnvX2bv7w@EH%22%20title=%22Java%20(JDK)%20%E2%80%93%20Try%20It%20Online%22%3ETry%20it%20online!%3C/a%3E):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class TestClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = ";databaseName=([^;]*)";
        final String string = "jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:1440;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER2019;databaseName=ab_cd_e;integratedSecurity=false\n" + "jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:1440;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER2019;integratedSecurity=false;databaseName=ab_cd_e";
         final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
         final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
         while (matcher.find()) {
           System.out.println("Name: " + matcher.group(1));
         }
    }
}
```

Prints

Name: ab_cd_e
Name: ab_cd_e

Answer (score 0):

from here [How to extract a substring using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)

```
String mydata = "jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:1440;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER2019;databaseName=ab_cd_e;integratedSecurity=false";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("databaseName=(\w+)(|;$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

output:

> ab_cd_e

Comment: The pattern assumes the databasename is at the end of the string, which is not the case for the second string.

Comment: I think you mean either a `;` or the end of the string `$` like `databaseName=(\w+)(?:;|$)`